# XSLT 1.0: search an attribute and add to parent element

Tags: xslt-1.0

**XML Input 1:**

```
<wine grape="chardonnay">
    <product>Carneros</product>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>10.99</price>
    <Field attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)"/>
    <Field id="5" attributes=""/>
    <Field id="6" attributes=""/>
    <Field line="19"/>
</wine>
```

**XML Input 2:**

```
<wine grape="chardonnay">
    <product>Carneros</product>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>10.99</price>
    <Method attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)">
        <Argument location="f0:13"/>
    </Method>
    <Field line="19" attributes=""/>
</wine>
```

**XML output:**

```
<wine grape="chardonnay" msgid="237">
  <product>Carneros</product>
  <year>1997</year>
  <price>10.99</price>
  <Method attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)">
    <Argument location="f0:13"/>
  </Method>
  <Field line="19"/>
</wine>
```

The task logic is as follows:
    grad the first appearance attribute content (i.e. `attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)")`
    and add it in the parent element.
    Notice that the `attributes` can be in the `Field` node or the `Method` node.
    In addition, rename from `attributes` to `msgid` and convert `gccxml(msgid=237)` to `msgid="237"`
    To conclude: the XML output should only update the parent element with msgid="237"

```
Basically, it is quite easy to do 'hard coded' by grabing a specific attribute from a given node and copy to its parent element. 

In here, the complexity is to search thru the 'Field' and 'Method' nodes, to grad the first occurance where the 'attribute' is not null, to do some string manipulation and place it its the parent element.
```

Basically, it is quite easy to do 'hard coded' by grabing a specific attribute from a given node and copy to its parent element.

```
In here, the complexity is to search thru the 'Field' and 'Method' nodes, to grad the first occurance where the 'attribute' is not null, to do some string manipulation and place it its the parent element.
```

In here, the complexity is to search thru the 'Field' and 'Method' nodes, to grad the first occurance where the 'attribute' is not null, to do some string manipulation and place it its the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

> The task logic is as follows: grad the first appearance attribute
>   content (i.e. attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)") and add it in the parent
>   element.

This part can be accomplished easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="msgid">
            <xsl:value-of select="//@attributes[string(.)][1]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> In addition, rename from attributes to msgid ...

We've done that already...

> ... and convert gccxml(msgid=237) to msgid="237"

The logic of this conversion is not quite clear.

---

### Edit

To extract the number after `gccxml(msgid=` use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(//@attributes[string(.)][1], 'msgid='), ')')"/>
```

Comment: 1. The conversion logic:

Comment: attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)"    ---> msgid="237"
attributes="gccxml(msgid=238)"    ---> msgid="238"
attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"    ---> msgid="239"
attributes="gccxml(msgid=240)"    ---> msgid="240"
attributes="gccxml(msgid=241)"    ---> msgid="241"
attributes="gccxml(msgid=242)"    ---> msgid="242"

Comment: grab the number appears after the 'gccxml(msgid=' and place this value in the parent attribute as msgid="237"

Comment: Another issue is to get rid of null attributes. If 'attributes' is null, then don't place it in the output
For instance:

Before:
<Field id="5" attributes=""/> 
After:
<Field id="5"/>

Comment: Suggestion: (probably can be done differently)
<xsl:variable name="temp" select="//@attributes[string(.)]"/>
<xsl:variable name="temp1" select="substring-after($temp, 'gccxml(msgid=')"/>
<xsl:variable name="temp2" select="substring-before($temp1, ')')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$temp2"/>

Comment: Another issue: In the above solution (by michael.hor257k), the
first msgid is grabbed. 

New logic: wine[@id] that matches Field[@context]

For instance: <wine id="_7" grape="chardonnay">
              <Field id="3" context="_7" attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"/>


The id="7" matches context="7", so take the attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)

Comment: XML input:
<wine id="_7" grape="chardonnay">
    <product>Carneros</product>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>10.99</price>
    <Field id="5" context="_8" gccxml(msgid=235)/>
    <Field id="3" context="_7" attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"/>
    <Field id="6" attributes=""/>
    <Field line="19"/>
</wine>

XML output:
<wine grape="chardonnay" msgid="239">
  <product>Carneros</product>
  <year>1997</year>
  <price>10.99</price>
  <Method attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)">
    <Argument location="f0:13"/>
  </Method>
  <Field line="19"/>
</wine>

Comment: @Dan **1.** Please do not post code in comments. -- **2.** For "new logic", post a new question.