# XSLT 1.0: search an attribute and add to parent element (part-2)

Tags: xslt-1.0

Using XSLT 1.0 I need to transform this:

---

```
<wine id="_7" grape="chardonnay"> 
    <product>Carneros</product>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>10.99</price>
    <Method context="_5" attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)">
        <Argument location="f0:13"/>
    </Method>
    <Field id="_3" context="_7" attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"/>
    <Field id="_4" line="19" attributes=""/>
    <Method context="_8" attributes="">
        <Argument location="f0:13"/>
    </Method>
</wine>
```

> - into this:
>
>   XML Output-1:

```
<wine grape="chardonnay" msgid="239">
   <product>Carneros</product>
   <year>1997</year>
   <price>10.99</price>
   <Method context="_5" attributes="gccxml(msgid=237)">
        <Argument location="f0:13"/>
    </Method>
    <Field id="3" context="_7" attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"/>
    <Field id="4" line="19"/>
    <Method context="_8">
        <Argument location="f0:13"/>
    </Method>
</wine>
```

The logic on how to accomplish 'XML Output-1' is as follows:
    ============================================================ 
    - Logic 1:
    ----------
    search for either 'Field[@context]' or 'Method[@context]' nodes that matches the wine[@id].

```
For instance: 
<wine id="_7" grape="chardonnay"> 
<Field id="_3" context="_7" attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"/>

To conclude:
The wine[id="_7"] matches Field[context="_7"], so add the attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"
in 'wine' element (i.e. msgid="239")

Result:
<wine grape="chardonnay" msgid="239">

- Logic 2:
----------
If 'Field' or 'Method' nodes includes attributes="" (null attribute),
then delete the attributes="" in output.

For Instance:
1. <Field id="4" line="19"/>
2. <Method context="_8">
```

> In addition, I need to transfer this:

XML Input-2

---

```
 <wine id="_5" grape="chardonnay"> 
        <product>Carneros</product>
        <year>1997</year>
        <price>10.99</price>
        <Field id="_9" line="19" attributes=""/>
        <Method context="_5" attributes="gccxml(msgid=235)">
            <Argument location="f0:13"/>
        </Method>
        <Field id="_3" context="_7" attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"/>
        <Field id="_4" line="19" attributes=""/>
    </wine>
```

> Into this

XML Output-2:

```
<wine grape="chardonnay" msgid="235">
   <product>Carneros</product>
   <year>1997</year>
   <price>10.99</price>
   <Field id="_9" line="19"/>
   <Method context="_5" attributes="gccxml(msgid=235)">
        <Argument location="f0:13"/>
    </Method>
    <Field id="3" context="_7" attributes="gccxml(msgid=239)"/>
    <Field id="4" line="19"/>
</wine>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please edit your question and make it **readable** - e.g. make sure code is formatted as code, and the rest of the text is not.

Comment: I edited the question the best I could. Is there a video on youtube tutorial to demonstrate how to format and work with the web interface?

Comment: very nice!  and what about the question regarding 'Logic 2' above?

Comment: @Dan You should have posted your comment under my answer, so that I get notified. I have only seen this by pure coincidence. And I haven't seen your other requirement because, sadly, your question is still a mess and "Logic 2" appears in a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> search for either 'Field[@context]' or 'Method[@context]' nodes that
>   matches the wine[@id].

That's easy to do by using a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** -  XSLT's built-in mechanism to handle cross-references. Once that's done, it's just a rerun of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123564/xslt-1-0-search-an-attribute-and-add-to-parent-element):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="msg" match="Field|Method" use="@context"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="msgid">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(key('msg', @id)/@attributes, 'msgid='), ')')"/>      
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To remove empty attributes of `Field` and `Method` elemmnts, simply add an empty template that matches them:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[parent::Field or parent::Method][not (string())]"/>
```